# Inserting html into the current tab through chrome extention?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to insert some extra code into the current tab page in chrome using an extension
i.e add a submit button on top of the page. Where does this go? and how would I initialize every page like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put this in your `manifest.json`,

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["example.js"],
  "css": ["example.css"]
}]
```

then `example.js` and `example.css` will be injected into every page you visit. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html for more information.

Comment: thanks for the code mate, it works fine, however, my js is suppose to insert this huge <H1>THIS IS A TEXT</H1> in there, and what happens right now is that it loads the normal page then it reloads it again with my H1 text, how can I prevent that? so just have it in serted in the first load.